# Creating a column with series of numbers in a dataframe (python)

Tags: python, dataframe, numbers, pandas-groupby, series

I have the following table (df):

| ColumnA | ColumnB | Blocks | Groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 32 | 1 | A1 |
| E | 99 | 2 | A1 |
| I | 76 | 3 | A1 |
| l | 55 | 4 | A1 |
| m | 27 | 5 | A1 |
| A | 12 | 1 | A2 |
| F | 123 | 2 | A2 |
| k | 80 | 3 | A2 |
| m | 27 | 4 | A2 |
| n | 67 | 5 | A2 |
| C | 44 | 1 | A3 |
| H | 87 | 2 | A3 |
| J | 231 | 3 | A3 |
| n | 67 | 4 | A3 |
| o | 34 | 5 | A4 |
| D | 76 | 1 | A4 |
| G | 65 | 2 | A4 |

I would like to add another additional column which contains list of IDs based on the Groups column. For group A1 it should be 101,102,103,... A2 it should be 201, 202, 203,... The output table should look like the following:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | Blocks | Groups | IDs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 32 | 1 | A1 | 101 |
| E | 99 | 2 | A1 | 102 |
| I | 76 | 3 | A1 | 103 |
| l | 55 | 4 | A1 | 104 |
| m | 27 | 5 | A1 | 105 |
| A | 12 | 1 | A2 | 201 |
| F | 123 | 2 | A2 | 202 |
| k | 80 | 3 | A2 | 203 |
| m | 27 | 4 | A2 | 204 |
| n | 67 | 5 | A2 | 205 |
| C | 44 | 1 | A3 | 301 |
| H | 87 | 2 | A3 | 302 |
| J | 231 | 3 | A3 | 303 |
| n | 67 | 4 | A3 | 304 |
| o | 34 | 5 | A4 | 401 |
| D | 76 | 1 | A4 | 402 |
| G | 65 | 2 | A4 | 403 |

What I tried so far?

```
n = 4
TGn = round(len(df)/n)
idx = set(df.index // TGn)
df['IDs'] = (((df.index // TGn) + 1) * 100) + df.groupby('Groups').cumcount() + 1
```

This does not align with the group names (A1, A2, A3, A4). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str.slice(1)` to extract the group number, and cast it into an integer type:

```
df['IDs'] = df.groupby('Groups').cumcount() + df['Groups'].str.slice(1).astype('int64') * 100 + 1
```

If the group name may have more than one characters before the numeric part, you could use `str.replace`:

```
df['IDs'] = df.groupby('Groups').cumcount() + df.Groups.str.replace(
    r'.*?(\d+)', r'\1', regex=True).astype('int64') * 100 + 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But the problem is the original data has A11, A12, AB11, AB12. Hence, I get an error if I use str.slice(1)

Comment: @MuSu18 My edit should be enough to process AB11 or AB12, but it would make no difference between A11 and A12. You should give some precisions about how you want to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

try using `ngroup` to give each group the same ID. I have make them as 100,200, ... so on` then I have added cumcount() result to them.

```
x = df.groupby('Groups')
y = x.ngroup().add(1).mul(100)
z = x.cumcount()+1
df['IDs'] = y+z
```

---

**df:**

|  | ColumnA | ColumnB | Blocks | Groups | IDs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | B | 32 | 1 | A1 | 101 |
| 1 | E | 99 | 2 | A1 | 102 |
| 2 | I | 76 | 3 | A1 | 103 |
| 3 | l | 55 | 4 | A1 | 104 |
| 4 | m | 27 | 5 | A1 | 105 |
| 5 | A | 12 | 1 | A2 | 201 |
| 6 | F | 123 | 2 | A2 | 202 |
| 7 | k | 80 | 3 | A2 | 203 |
| 8 | m | 27 | 4 | A2 | 204 |
| 9 | n | 67 | 5 | A2 | 205 |
| 10 | C | 44 | 1 | A3 | 301 |
| 11 | H | 87 | 2 | A3 | 302 |
| 12 | J | 231 | 3 | A3 | 303 |
| 13 | n | 67 | 4 | A3 | 304 |
| 14 | o | 34 | 5 | A4 | 401 |
| 15 | D | 76 | 1 | A4 | 402 |
| 16 | G | 65 | 2 | A4 | 403 |

**Edit:**
You can get the group number from Groups (A1, A2....) also. I didn't check that while writing the answer.

```
df['IDs'] = (df.Groups.str.extract('(\d$)').astype(int).mul(100))[0] + df.groupby('Groups').cumcount()+1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I alter this for n groups? n being user input.